# How to enter path of the lua file and open it(not in same dirrectory)

Tags: windows, lua

so i want to read file, it named main.lua, i have this in test.lua which i open up, and when i do, it prints things that are wrote in main.lua

```lua
local mainfile = ""
local open = io.open 
function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "rb")
    if not file then return nil end
    local content = file:read "*a"
    file:close()
    return content
end
local filecontent = read_file(mainfile);
print(filecontent)
```

mainfile is path to the file of main.lua, but how do i enter path to it?

Method to enter path in Lua to open file

Comment: `local mainfile = "C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\File.txt"`  If path or filename contains non-English symbols then use ANSI codepage (win1252 in Europe)

Comment: so how and where to enter it so Lua can now understand what symbols are?

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to read a path from *standard input* (user input), and store it as a string in the variable `mainfile`? Or are you trying to hard-code a path in *test.lua*, and you are confused on how to specify this path (e.g., *absolute* vs. *relative* paths)?

Comment: @freziyt223 - Give an example of file path you have problems with.  In your code `mainfile = ""` is empty, but file name cannot be empty.

Comment: so i have the path "C:\Users\Nazar\Documents\main.lua" and i enter it when code runs

Comment: @Oka so my script is working if i make variable with path ```
local enterpath = "C:\\Users\\Nazar\\Videos\\test.lua" with \\. But i want it to have ability to convert \ into \\ if i enter windows path in with io.read() like local enterpath = io.read() then i enter "C:\Users\Nazar\Videos\test.lua" and then it has to convert \ into \\ so script can read it.

Comment: @ESkri i made it, everything works if i enter path without "", like C:\Users\Nazar\Videos\test.lua, thanks, i wanted to know, what if i'd had Ukrainian symbols in my path, how do i make it readable for lua?

Comment: @freziyt223 - Lua does not read your strings, so you can write any symbols in any encoding.  But Lua invokes OS function to open your file, and OS requires all filename symbols to be encoded in ANSI codepage.  Probably, yours is Win-1251.  There is a [Lua library](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/44a88f64f9a497919db4ad8c28259a8f) to convert strings between UTF-8 and ANSI codepage.

Comment: @Eskri if i have path C:\Users\Nazar\Відео\test.lua, lua can't read Ukrainian symbols, so how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your Windows non-Unicode codepage is set to 1251

```
reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage /v ACP
```

2. Save library file [`win-125x.lua`](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/44a88f64f9a497919db4ad8c28259a8f) in your Lua modules' folder.
3. Make sure your script is creates as UTF-8 text

```
require("win-125x")

local mainfile = [[C:\Users\Nazar\Відео\test.lua]]
mainfile = utf8_to_win(mainfile)

function read_file(path)
    local file = io.open(path, "rb")
    if not file then return nil end
    local content = file:read "*a"
    file:close()
    return content
end
local filecontent = read_file(mainfile)
print(filecontent)
```

Comment: i use now chcp 65001 and i'll try it, thanks for the help

Comment: As you have problems with `io.read()` + `chcp 65001` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77020680/lua-how-to-enter-non-english-symbols-in-io-read), you may use `chcp 1251`.  With 1251 codepage `io.read()` will work correctly, and you don't need to use `utf8_to_win` at all - just pass the string from `io.read()` to `io.open()` without modifications.