# Lua how to enter non English symbols in io.read()

Tags: lua, io, symbols

I have code that runs some commands, i have io.read() that has to read user input and understand which command user used(or not used), and i have an issue when i enter "шлях"(path on English) and print it to see if it works, i get nothing, so he can't read Ukrainian symbols in io.read(). I want to know how to fix it or maybe make it sideways? my code with commands list
[with English symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEQ5F.png)
[with Ukrainian symbols(cyrillic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6emJ.png)

```
require("commandsfortest")
Read = {}
os.execute("chcp 65001")
print('Hello this is starter programm from freziyt223, to get more information type "help"||Привіт, це початкова програма від freziyt223, щоб отримати більше інформації введіть "інформація"')

local start = io.read()

for group, commands in pairs(Command) do
    for _, cmd in ipairs(commands) do
        if start == cmd then
            
            if group == "path" then
              
                local enterpath = io.read()
                local returnedpath = enterpath:gsub("\\", "/")
                local open = io.open

                function Read:file(path)
    
                    local file = open(path, "rb")
                    if not file then return nil end
                    local content = file:read("*a")
                    file:close()
                    return content
                      
                end
                local Readfile = Read:file(returnedpath);
                print(Readfile)
            elseif group == "file" then
                                
                local entercommandname = io.read()
                function Read:command(command)

                    local result = io.popen(command):read("*a")
                    print(result)
                end
                Read:command(entercommandname)

            elseif group == "script" then
                io.write("Програма: ")
                local prg = io.read()
                io.write("Команда: ")
                local scr = io.read()
                local run = io.popen(prg, "w")
                if not run then return nil end
                run:write(scr)
                run:close()
            end
        end
    end
end
print(start)
```

```
Command = {
    ["path"] = {
        "path",
        "path ",
        "Path",
        "Path ",
        "шлях",
        "шлях ",
        "Шлях",
        "Шлях "
    },
    ["file"] = {
        "application",
        "application ",
        "Application",
        "Application ",
        "команда",
        "команда ",
        "Команда",
        "Команда "
    },
    ["script"] = {
        "script",
        "script ",
        "Script",
        "Script ",
        "рукопис",
        "рукопис ",
        "Рукопис",
        "Рукопис "
    }
}
```

as you can see i tried to execute UTF-8 enconding which helped me to print Ukrainian symbols, but didn't helped here

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @shingo yes, i do

Comment: Windows has a problem, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38164979/6196568  Either you change stdin mode to binary and recompile lua, or you process commands in multibyte encoding.

Comment: how to make stdin binary and recompile?

Comment: Use `setmode`. Have you ever compiled lua?